# AutoHotkey GetWinTitle when current window changes

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I'm trying to make an ahk script that alerts you when a new window is opened (or brought back to focus). In other words, I want it to detect when the current window changes. I've tried comparing the window names to detect a difference:

```
    0::
    WinGetTitle, title, A
    windowTitle=%title%
    MsgBox, "The current window is %title%."
    return

    9::
    WinGetTitle, title2, A
    if (%title2% = %title%)
    {
        success=1
    }
    else
    {
        MsgBox, "The current window changed to %title2%."
    }
    return
```

But, 

 1)I'm apparently using illegal characters in the variables; and 

 2)I'd rather use a different method than this;


 Thanks in advance!


 P.S. I would like the alert to contain the name of the current window.

Comment: When using parentheses in `if`, don't use `%` because the variables are autoexpanded already.

Comment: Wow! It worked! When I read the error message I looked to me as if I couldn't use quotes in a variable. Thanks!

Comment: See  also [SetTimer - Example2](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#Examples).

Answer (score 2):

```
CurrentTitle := ""

SetTimer, CheckWindow, 1000
return

CheckWindow:
    WinGetTitle, NewTitle, A
    if (CurrentTitle != NewTitle){
        ToolTip % "Window changed to: " NewTitle
        CurrentTitle := NewTitle
    }
    return
```

Comment: I'd prefer using a `setTimer`, so the script execution does not block

Comment: @Blauhirn - Updated to use SetTimer